# from keyword in wrong place

Tags: sql, oracle

Display realtor staff number, name, annual salary as Annual Salary, monthly salary as Monthly Salary, and age as Age. Round monthly salary to 2 decimal places. Round age to years. Sort output by staff age descending.  If there is no birthdate on the record, then list the age as "Unknown".
This is the code I have to answer the question.

```
select st_staffno, st_name, st_salary "Annual Salary",(st_salary/12) as "Monthly Salary"   
    decode (st_birthdate, null, 'unknown'), 
    round sysdate ((st.birthdate)/365.25,0) as "Age"
from staff
order by "Age" desc;
```

It is returning a From keyword not found where expected error.

Comment: You're missing a `,` on the end of the first line (after `as "Monthly Salary"`)

Comment: A great sql debugging technique is to start removing parts of your query until it runs successfully. That will help you narrow down to the part(s) causing the syntax error.

Comment: select st_staffno, st_name, st_salary "Annual Salary", round (st_salary/12,0) as "Monthly Salary",    
    decode (st_birthdate, null, 'unknown', (round ((sysdate - st_birthdate)/365.25,0))) as "Age"
from staff
order by "Age" desc;

Comment: change st_salary "Annual Salary"  into  st_salary as "Annual Salary"

Answer (score 2):

You should tag SQL questions with the DBMS you are using. From `DECODE` I conclude it's Oracle. You get `ORA-00923 "FROM keyword not found where expected"`, when the query parser thinks that the `SELECT` clause is finished, but no `FROM` keyword follows. So what may make the DBMS think the `SELECT` clause is ended? This usually occurs, when you miss a comma betwen the selected expressions.

Your mistakes:

1. There is a comma missing after `as "Monthly Salary"`.
2. Your age calculation is syntactically off.
3. You are using `st.birthdate`, but there is no `st` table name or alias in your query. I suppose the column name is `st_birthdate`?

The corrected query:

```
select
  st_staffno,
  st_name,
  st_salary as "Annual Salary",
  st_salary / 12 as "Monthly Salary"   
  decode(st_birthdate, null, 'unknown'), 
  round((sysdate - st_birthdate) / 365.25, 0) as "Age"
from staff
order by "Age" desc;
```

Instead of `DECODE` you could also use standard SQL's `CASE WHEN`. And to literally apply "then list the age as Unknown" you'd have to combine the last two expressions. And you are missing "Round monthly salary to 2 decimal places".

```
select
  st_staffno,
  st_name,
  st_salary as "Annual Salary",
  round(st_salary / 12, 2) as "Monthly Salary"   
  case when st_birthdate is null
       then 'unknown'
       else to_char(round((sysdate - st_birthdate) / 365.25, 0))
  end as "Age"
from staff
order by st_birthdate nulls last;
```

At last: We don't usually calculate the age from the real length of a year. When born on the 1st of April, we turn a year older on every 1st of April at midnight.

```
extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from st_birthdate) -
case when to_char(sysdate, 'mmdd') < to_char(st_birthdate, 'mmdd')
  then 1 else 0 
end as "Age"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need an immediate bracket `(`after round as round is a function like

`.. round(sysdate/362.25,0)` and do check your logic for evaluating Age column it should be some decode condition like `..decode(birthdate,round(sysdate..ontrue),null (onfalse)`